# zf2 breadcrumbs - child page

Tags: zend-framework2, breadcrumbs

I have a problem with the configuration of bradcrumbs of my application.

I begin by report configuration for my module :

```
'corso' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/corso[/:action[/:id]]',
        'constraints' => array( 'id' => '[0-9]*', 'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'corso/Controller/corso',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

The controller has the usual methods index, add and edit action for basic crud operation

As you can see from the configuration file add and edit actions are not child route.

I would like to get a bradcrumbs of this type

home> index action controller> add / edit action

the first and second elements are links.

this is  partial view of breadcrumbs

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><i class="iconfa-home"></i></a> <span class="separator"></span></li>
<?php $active = $container->findActive($navigation) ?>
<?php foreach($this->pages as $page): ?>
    <?php /* @var $page \Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc */ ?>
    <?php if( ! $page->isActive()): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>"><?php echo $page->getLabel() ?></a>
            <span class="divider">/</span>
        </li>
    <?php else: ?>
        <li class="active">
            <?php if($container->getLinkLast()): ?><a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>"><?php endif ?>
                <?php echo $page->getLabel() ?>
                <?php if($container->getLinkLast()): ?><a href="<?php echo $page->getHref() ?>"><?php endif ?>
        </li>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

What should I add?

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(

        array(
            'label' => 'corso',
            'route' => 'corso',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
      -----
    ),
),
```

thanks

edit:
i use zf2 helper for bredcrumbs

```
$this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0)->setPartial(array('partial/breadcrumb', 'corso'));
```

Comment: Have you tried the breadcrumbs helper from zf2? http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.breadcrumbs.html

Comment: i  use it. the partial render is for customize html. I would like to figure out how to set the configuration to get the result I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is example in Zend\Navigation Quick Start for nested pages:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.navigation.quick-start.html#quick-start

In your case, it should be like this:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label'  => 'corso',
            'route'  => 'corso',
            'action' => 'index',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'add action ',
                    'route' => 'corso',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'edit action ',
                    'route' => 'corso',
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```